# Regular expression 2 digits 10 letters/digits

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression, but something isn't working for me, the requirements are the following:

1. Min length is 1
2. Max length is 12
3. The first 2 symbols must be numbers
4. Next 10 must be either letters or numbers

This is what I have so far

```
/^[0-9]{0,2}[a-z][A-Z][0-9]{0,10}$/
```

Can you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is not workign with the given expression? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: You say the min length is 1, but `[a-z][A-Z]` already requires 2. And `[0-9]{0,2}` means the first two chars can be ``[a-z][A-Z]``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `^[0-9]{0,2}[a-z][A-Z][0-9]{0,10}$` matches 0, 1 or 2 digits at the start.

Then it matches 2 chars `[a-z][A-Z]` being a lowercase and an uppercase char A-Z which should be present in the string, and also makes the string length at least 2 chars.

---

You can make the second digit optional, and use 1 character class for the letters or numbers.

The length then has a minumum of 1, and a maximum of 12.

```
^(?!\d[a-zA-Z])\d\d?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\d[a-zA-Z])`  negative lookahead, assert not a digit followed by a-zA-Z
- `\d\d?` Match 1 or 2 digits
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}` Match 0-10 repetitions of any of the listed ranges
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9TjEk/1)

Or a version withtout a lookahead as suggested by @[Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte) in the comments, matching a single digit and optionally a second digit followed by 0-10 repetitions of the listed ranges:

```
^\d(?:\d[A-Za-z\d]{0,10})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG93zS/1)

Comment: But.. "The first 2 symbols must be numbers".

Comment: @Scratte Ah true, let me update that

Comment: I think this would do as well `^\d(?:\d[A-Za-z\d]{0,10})?$`. Based on your first suggestion :) It forces the second to be a digit when there's more than one character.

Comment: @Scratte Nice one, that will also match.